# Fetch data from a Core Controller in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, fetch, codeigniter-3

I'm working on a Social Network app.
I'm facing a problem in which I'm trying to get the name and username from a table called users in my database.
To be able to do this without accessing to all the controllers individually I had to create a Core controller with the name of MY_Controller.

Here is the problem(MY_Controller without the public $users):

```
<?php

class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller
{

//public $users = array('username' => $this->input->post('username')); 


    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        //Get user data to make it available for both Admin and Public Controllers
        $this->load->model('User_model');
        $this->users = $this->User_model->get_list();

        //Load Menu Library
        $this->load->library('menu');
        $this->pages = $this->menu->get_pages();

        // Brand/Logo
        $this->favicon = 'https://blogpersonal.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/favicon-v2-150x150.png';
        $this->brand = 'Some Name';
        $this->description = 'Some Description';
        $this->credits = 'https://blogpersonal.net/';
        $this->version = '1.1.1';
    }
}

class Admin_Controller extends MY_Controller
{

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        if (!$this->session->is_admin) {
            redirect('admin/login');
        }

        //some code here

    }
}

class Public_Controller extends MY_Controller{
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();

        //some code here

    }

}

class Social_Controller extends MY_Controller
{

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        if (!$this->session->is_member) {
            redirect('dashboard/login');
        }

        //some code here

    }
}
```

As you can see I loaded the User_model using the __construct function to make it available and use it in all controllers.

I want to fetch data in a folder called templates.
**views>templates>any document** but when I try to fetch it in a view like this:

```
    <?php if($this->users) : ?>
        <li class="dropdown user user-menu">
          <!-- Menu Toggle Button -->
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            <!-- The user image in the navbar-->
            <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/img/user2-160x160.jpg" class="user-image" alt="User Image">
            <!-- hidden-xs hides the username on small devices so only the image appears. -->
            <span class="hidden-xs"><?php echo $this->users['username']; ?></span>
          </a>

        </li>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

**THIS IS THE OLD ERROR**. it shows me an error. Am I doing something wrong? Can somebody explain me how to fix it. This is the first time in which I'm unable to fetch data.

This is the result that I get:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined variable: users
>
> Filename: Templates/public.php
>
> Line Number: 161
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\codeigniter\application\views\Templates\public.php
>   Line: 161 Function: _error_handler
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\codeigniter\application\libraries\Template.php
>   Line: 34 Function: view
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\codeigniter\application\controllers\Pages.php
>   Line: 12 Function: load
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\codeigniter\index.php Line: 315 Function:
>   require_once

Here is my model(User_model) in case you might need it:

```
<?php

class User_model extends CI_MODEL
{

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->table = 'users';
    }

    public function get_list()
    {
        $query = $this->db->get($this->table);
        return $query->result();
    }

    public function get($id)
    {
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $query = $this->db->get($this->table);
        return $query->row();
    }

    public function add($data)
    {
        $this->db->insert($this->table, $data);
    }

    public function update($id, $data)
    {
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $this->db->update($this->table, $data);
    }

    public function delete($id)
    {
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $this->db->delete($this->table);
    }

    public function login($username, $password)
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from($this->table);
        $this->db->where('username', $username);
        $this->db->where('password', $password);
        $this->db->limit(1);

        $query = $this->db->get();

        if ($query->num_rows() == 1) {
            return $query->row()->id;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Now with the changes that were suggested to me, it now shows a new error:

**The New error:**

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice Message:  Undefined index: username Filename:
>   Templates/public.php Line Number: 168
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\codeigniter\application\views\Templates\public.php
>   Line: 168 Function: _error_handler
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\codeigniter\application\libraries\Template.php
>   Line: 34 Function: view
>
> File:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\codeigniter\application\controllers\public\Dashboard.php
>   Line: 13 Function: load
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\codeigniter\index.php Line: 315 Function:
>   require_once

Now if a un-comment the public $users in the Core controller(MY_Controller) ,it shows me a new error as well:

**New error with public $users out of __construct function**

> Fatal error: Constant expression contains invalid operations in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\codeigniter\application\core\MY_Controller.php on line
>   6 A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Compile Error
>
> Message: Constant expression contains invalid operations
>
> Filename: core/MY_Controller.php
>
> Line Number: 6
>
> Backtrace:

Here is a picture in which I'm trying to get the data to:

[image]

Am I doing something wrong? thanks for helping.

Here is the view (public.php) file:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <?php if(!$this->session->is_member) : ?>
          <li><?php echo anchor('public/users/login', 'Login'); ?></li>
          <li><?php echo anchor('public/users/register', 'Register'); ?></li>
          <?php else : ?>
            <!-- Messages: style can be found in dropdown.less-->
            <li class="dropdown messages-menu">
              <!-- Menu toggle button -->
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>
                <span class="label label-success">4</span>
              </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li class="header">You have 4 messages</li>
                <li>
                  <!-- inner menu: contains the messages -->
                  <ul class="menu">
                    <li><!-- start message -->
                      <a href="#">
                        <div class="pull-left">
                          <!-- User Image -->
                          <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/img/user2-160x160.jpg" class="img-circle" alt="User Image">
                        </div>
                        <!-- Message title and timestamp -->
                        <h4>
                          Support Team
                          <small><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 5 mins</small>
                        </h4>
                        <!-- The message -->
                        <p>Why not buy a new awesome theme?</p>
                      </a>
                    </li>
                    <!-- end message -->
                  </ul>
                  <!-- /.menu -->
                </li>
                <li class="footer"><a href="#">See All Messages</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <!-- /.messages-menu -->
            <!-- Notifications Menu -->
            <li class="dropdown notifications-menu">
              <!-- Menu toggle button -->
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                <i class="fa fa-bell-o"></i>
                <span class="label label-warning">10</span>
              </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li class="header">You have 10 notifications</li>
                <li>
                  <!-- Inner Menu: contains the notifications -->
                  <ul class="menu">
                    <li><!-- start notification -->
                      <a href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-users text-aqua"></i> 5 new members joined today
                      </a>
                    </li>
                    <!-- end notification -->
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="footer"><a href="#">View all</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <!-- Tasks Menu -->
            <li class="dropdown tasks-menu">
              <!-- Menu Toggle Button -->
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                <i class="fa fa-flag-o"></i>
                <span class="label label-danger">9</span>
              </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li class="header">You have 9 tasks</li>
                <li>
                  <!-- Inner menu: contains the tasks -->
                  <ul class="menu">
                    <li><!-- Task item -->
                      <a href="#">
                        <!-- Task title and progress text -->
                        <h3>
                          Design some buttons
                          <small class="pull-right">20%</small>
                        </h3>
                        <!-- The progress bar -->
                        <div class="progress xs">
                          <!-- Change the css width attribute to simulate progress -->
                          <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-aqua" style="width: 20%" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="20" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
                            <span class="sr-only">20% Complete</span>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </a>
                    </li>
                    <!-- end task item -->
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="footer">
                  <a href="#">View all tasks</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <!-- User Account Menu -->
            <?php if($this->users) : ?>
                <li class="dropdown user user-menu">
                  <!-- Menu Toggle Button -->
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    <!-- The user image in the navbar-->
                    <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/img/user2-160x160.jpg" class="user-image" alt="User Image">
                    <!-- hidden-xs hides the username on small devices so only the image appears. -->
                    <span class="hidden-xs"><?php echo $this->users['username']; ?></span>
                  </a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <!-- The user image in the menu -->
                    <li class="user-header">
                    <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/img/user2-160x160.jpg" class="img-circle" alt="User Image">
                      <p><?php echo $this->users['name']; ?> - Web Developer<small>Member since Nov. 2012</small></p>
                    </li>
                    <!-- Menu Body -->
                    <li class="user-body">
                      <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">
                          <a href="#">Followers</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">
                          <a href="#">Sales</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">
                          <a href="#">Friends</a>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <!-- /.row -->
                    </li>
                    <!-- Menu Footer-->
                    <li class="user-footer">
                      <div class="pull-left">
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-flat">Profile</a>
                      </div>
                      <div class="pull-right">
                        <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>public/users/logout" class="btn btn-default btn-flat">Sign out</a>
                      </div>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <li>
                <a href="#" data-toggle="control-sidebar"><i class="fa fa-gears"></i></a>
            </li>
          <?php endif; ?>
          </ul>
```

Comment: You should use as a property. public $users; and in your construct ($this->users = $this->User_model->get_list();. When you declare a variable in a function, will only be accessible in that function (or if you pass as parameter to another).

Comment: Well, I made the change as you suggested on my __construct function but it just works if I do a foreach; doing an if condition is still not working. What do you mean by using it as a property?. I tried doing my __construct function public but I was unable to see any difference.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: @Kevin - you would have fired up Google and looked up what a Property of a class is and after that "ah ha" moment would have implemented webmasterdo's suggestion. So can you show your updated code with the changes?

Comment: Ok, so can we see the code where you are loading the view? That is where your issue is

Comment: For what reason did you attempt - public $users = array('username' => $this->input->post('username')); public $users=array(); is ALL you need to define it and init it. You cannot go running code in there.

Comment: I tried that long ago and I got an error of undefined variable

Answer (score 1):

You currently have this... and I am only showing snippets here...

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        //Get user data to make it available for both Admin and Public Controllers
        $this->load->model('User_model');
        $data['users'] = $this->User_model->get_list();

<<<<snip>>>>
```

It was suggested that you turn your locally defined $data['users'] into a **"Property"**

So we now have two changes...

1 Declare the Property

2 Set the property.

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller
{
    public $users = array(); // Add the property $user, safe def of an empty array

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        //Get user data to make it available for both Admin and Public Controllers
        $this->load->model('User_model');
        //$data['users'] = $this->User_model->get_list();
        // Give the property something to share. 
        $this->users = $this->User_model->get_list();


    <<<<snip>>>>
```

Now all of your controllers that extend your MY_Controller now have access to $this->users created in MY_Controller...

So you reference **$this->users** where you want to use it.

I'd suggest you read up on Classes, Properties, Methods and Inheritance to begin with. Usually that is enough to make you dangerous. It takes a little getting used to but its worth the effort...

**Update:**
In your controller that calls your View you would do
$data['users'] = $this->users;

And in your view, you now refer to it as $users->field_name just like before.
All we have done is define $users in your base class which is now accessible as $this->users so it's accessible to all your controllers / methods that extend the MY_Controller class.

Comment: It's showing me the same error :/.
Thanks for helping

Comment: So whats in public.php as this is where the error is occurring. Can you show that code please.

Comment: I updated my question, you can see there what I have so far. Thanks for helping, Maybe am I loading the view incorrectly?

Comment: Yep - in your controller you would set $data['users'] = $this->users; and pass that into your view. Then you refer to $users->the_field_name. You should read up on views etc in the Codeigniter user guide.

Comment: that's how it was in the very beginning and it did not work.

Comment: Yes, but we've given you the fix... So I don't understand why there isn't a flutter of keyboard key noises at your end, trying things out. You don't go changing things, see it fail and look glum... That's when I get a big grin and "Go Hunting" :) So what happens when you do as we have suggested?

Answer (score 0):

you currently have this.

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller
{

function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    //Get user data to make it available for both Admin and Public Controllers
    $this->load->model('User_model');
    $data['users'] = $this->User_model->get_list();
```

you should use $this->data['users'] in place of $data

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller
{

function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    //Get user data to make it available for both Admin and Public Controllers
    $this->load->model('User_model');
    $this->data['users'] = $this->User_model->get_list();
```

when you load your view use the code below

```
$this->load->view('view_name',$this->data);
```

it will show all your variable(in view) stored in parent classes construct function